# could not find oci pdo driver in windows

Tags: php, windows, oracle, apache, pdo

We installed apache and php on windows server 2008 to try to be connected with oracle database with php command.
We inserted in php.ini the following lign : extension_dir.
But when we tried to connect to oracle with php command that displays "could not find driver".
When we execute "phpinfo()" command we can see that "oci" is not enabled in pdo drivers.

Hope somebody can help us. Best regards, nico.

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php

To enable an extension, uncomment (remove initial semicolon) the line that looks like this:

```
extension=php_pdo_oci8.dll
```

Comment: php_pdo_oci8.dll was not present in the extension directory. I downloaded it and I added it into the directory and I wrote the line into the php.ini file. But that does not work, the driver is not found.

Comment: I put PHP manager in the IIS console but I don't understand why I need to do that. That does not work.

Comment: In there you can enable and disable extensions, try that.

Comment: Thanks for your help I found the solution. I was given a corrupted version of Oracle. Now I have no problem.